# iframe with user details in joomla

Tags: html, joomla

I have a site that can be published and has SSO. The SSO works with an iframe, the user's details are given in the querystring, and one of the details has to be hashed (MD5). E.g: 
http://www.come2play.com/channel_auth.asp?channel_id=9000&uid=123456&nick_name=The+Man&auth_sig=dc952e4371e04551684afbcbf12cf14c

One of my publishers uses joomla and wants to use the SSO. He's not a programmer and gave me access to his joomla system as an administrator. All I have to do is add the iframe with the user's details, but I have no idea where to begin.

I saw how to get the user's details here:
http:// docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object

Am I supposed to create a php page? A joomla artice? Extension? Module? Component? I'm not sure what is what, and my goal is quite simple. After I create the thing, where do I put it? (I have access to the web server).

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass details to something in an iframe, create a new folder in templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/ so that we can override the default behaviour.

wrapper
--tmpl
----default.php

You then need to copy the files from components/com_wrapper/views/wrapper

If you look at the file, you will see the following code:

```
<iframe <?php echo $this->wrapper->load; ?>
id="blockrandom"
name="iframe"
src="<?php echo $this->wrapper->url."?username=".$user->username."&email=".$user->email; ?>"
width="<?php echo $this->params->get( 'width' ); ?>"
height="<?php echo $this->params->get( 'height' ); ?>"
scrolling="<?php echo $this->params->get( 'scrolling' ); ?>"
align="top"
frameborder="0"
class="wrapper<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('pageclass_sfx')); ?>">
<?php echo JText::_( 'NO_IFRAMES' ); ?>
</iframe>
```

If you look at the src attribute, you can see that I'm passing in the username and email. You should be able to do the same for other parameters

Comment: I have tried this too. But Gmail does not show this nor Outlook. Where exactly it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone who may stumble across this and needs sometime simular.  I do have a page that sits within an iframe and I added a few extra bits to be able to connect it with the user DB:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
?>
```

The above is to connect to the DB and then you can from there place in fields to get your user's information:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="Nickname" value="<?php print($user->username); ?>">
  <?php
  if($user->username){
     print($user->username);
  }else{
     print("You need to <a href=\"http://yoursite.com/index.php/component/users/?view=registration\" title=\"Create an account\" target=\"_top\">register</a> to use chat.");
  }
  ?>
```

And/Or:

```
Real name: 
      <input type="hidden" name="Realname" value="<?php print($user->name); ?>">
      <?php print($user->name); ?>
```

Hope it helps anyone who needs it.